# How to choose between preposition OF and preposition FROM

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition is more appropriate or more colloquial in this context:

> The pupils **from** Berkeley High school have school from 9.00 am to 3.30 pm.

> The pupils **of** Berkeley High school have school from 9.00 am to 3.30 pm.

I would prefer FROM but I really can't say which one is better.

Comment: In conversation, I'd be more likely to say "from" if there were more than one school, and we're comparing school hours. If I were just discussing one school, I'd be more likely to use "of". Perhaps that's just my idiosyncrasy; here's no rule i know of for that,

Answer (score 1):

"From" suggests origin. It would be a good choice if the Berkeley students are not actually at the Berkeley school for the context of the conversation, but have come to somewhere else. For instance, in *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, the students *of* Hogwarts are joined by students *from* Beauxbatons Academy.

"Of" is a perfectly good choice if we're just discussing schools in the abstract; another would be "**at**."

> The pupils **at** Berkeley High school have school from 9.00 am to 3.30 pm.